# Cocoa: get NSWindow relative position

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, position, nswindow

Is there a way to say if a certain window "covers" another one, in a Cocoa app? Is it possible to get `[NSApp windows]` sorted by their relative (to each other) position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `-[NSApplication orderedWindows]` does. If a window is later in that array and its frame overlaps your window's, then it is at least partly covered (barring weirdness with custom window shapes).

Comment: Great: I should have seen it, what an oversight  :)

Comment: [[NSApplication sharedApplication] orderedWindows];